# Fab Icon disappers after click

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a collapsing toolbar layout and a FAB.
I dynamically change the FAB icon on click.
It works wells. But when the toolbar collapses and expanded again. Clicking on the FAB makes the icon disappear. When I collapse and expanded again, the icon appears, and the icon is changed!

layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarTitleCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarTitle"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/scrim" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java Code for toggling FAB icon

```
final FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
if (isSelected) {  
 fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MyActivity.this,R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
    fab.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
    } else {      fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MyActivity.this,R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
      fab.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
    }
    isSelected = !isSelected;
    }
    });
```

Comment: IMO, the problem is with the setColorFilter... Set background Tint instead and try..

Comment: @UmangBurman Tried, still same problem.

Comment: Your both if and else blocks represents same code, why is that?

Comment: No, the drawables are different

Comment: Sorry., Didn't notice that ...

Comment: Change it to some other color from White to blue and try

Comment: Try removing the color filter, see how it behaves

Comment: Found the problem!
Apparently there it is bug in support library 28.0.0-rc02
Changed to sdk 27 and working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in the material design library 28.0 which is already reported

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111316656

Comment: I'll echo this, as I wasted a lot of time trying to solve it yesterday, but I'll add that If you need a workaround in the meantime you can use a `LevelListDrawable` (or a `<level-list>`), and select the drawable indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

the fab hide behind  `<include layout="@layout/content"/>` layout. You should use  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your content layout. try this  and let me know.